# After Using react navigation react native app is not load

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a problem With this. I am very new to react-native. I am Building react native app. In there I have used React navigation.

This is my pakage.json file.

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^30.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.57.3",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.0-alpha.6"
  }
}
```

This is my App.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import Route from './src/routes';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Route/>
    );
  }
}
```

And There I  have created a Home.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        Add friends here!
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

There I have created route.js file like this.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './components/Home';

const Route = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
});

export default  Route;
```

After Creating These files.When I hit expo start --android It load nothing on the simulator. It just stuck on the loading screen. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding initial route

```
const Route = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
},
{
   initialRouteName: "Home",

});
```

Comment: Also wrap your text in <Text></tText>. Change the background color to #000 to see if there is  a difference. Maybe all works but your view is just white?